# Android Tools r20 won't build project with library projects using ant, says I'm missing project.properties in library but I'm not

Tags: android, ant, android-build

I have been using ant to build my project for months with no problems up until r20 that just came out yesterday. I basically just use the hooks provided by the default build file to do some minor changes. My project is using 2 library projects and the builds work fine from eclipse.. However I do official, signed builds with ant (which I have targets for creating builds where my app will connect to either production, staging or qa environments).
Here is the error message I'm getting:

> BUILD FAILED /Users/mwolfe/workspace/android-flex/app/build.xml:99:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /Users/mwolfe/lib/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:476:
>   ../shared/SomeSdk/sdk resolve to a path with no project.properties
>   file for project
>   /Users/mwolfe/workspace/android-flex/shared/SomeSdk/sdk

However I am sure there is a project.properties file in this folder and this worked fine before. Looking at line 476 in the build.xml for android it has this:

```
 <!-- clean target -->
<target name="clean" depends="-setup, -pre-clean"
        description="Removes output files created by other targets.">
    <delete dir="${out.absolute.dir}" verbose="${verbose}" />
    <delete dir="${gen.absolute.dir}" verbose="${verbose}" />

    <!-- if we know about a tested project or libraries, we clean them too. -->
    <if condition="${project.is.test}">
        <then>
            <property name="tested.project.absolute.dir" location="${tested.project.dir}" />
            <subant failonerror="true">
                <fileset dir="${tested.project.absolute.dir}" includes="build.xml" />
                <target name="clean" />
            </subant>
        </then>
    </if>

    <!-- get all the libraries -->
    <if>
        <condition><not><isset property="dont.do.deps" /></not></condition>
        <then>
 <!-- LINE 476 HERE: -->    <getlibpath libraryFolderPathOut="project.library.folder.path" />
            <if>
                <condition>
                    <isreference refid="project.library.folder.path" />
                </condition>
                <then>
                    <!-- clean the libraries with nodeps since we already
                         know about all the libraries even the indirect one -->
                    <subant
                            buildpathref="project.library.folder.path"
                            antfile="build.xml"
                            failonerror="true">
                        <target name="nodeps" />
                        <target name="clean" />
                    </subant>
                </then>
            </if>
        </then>
    </if>
</target>
```

Any ideas what is causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I figured out how to fix it. What happened was that, for whatever reason, when I originally wrote my own ant script I had my own clean target which I called all the subproject's clean targets, like so:

```
<target name="clean" depends="androidbuild.clean">

    <exec executable="sh" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build" />
        <arg value="clean" />
    </exec>
             <!-- remove the next 2 lines to fix the problem -->
    <ant target="clean" dir="${android.library.reference.1}" />
    <ant target="clean" dir="${android.library.reference.2}" />
</target>
```

This doesn't work anymore for some reason though and it appears the new ant build script android r20 provides handles this for me anyways, so removing the 2 clean calls above fixed the problem.

Note that the androidbuild.clean dependancy calls the parent build.xml's clean target which is defined in the $ANDROID_SDK/tools/ant/build.xml
When you import that script, do so like this:

```
<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" as="androidbuild" />
```

So that you can reference targets in that build file (ps, this also fixes eclipse from thinking your build.xml file has errors such that you don't need to copy and paste the android build.xml into your own file as others online have suggested).